# Convert .netCore 5.0.0 to .netFramework 4.0.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, nuget, csproj, .net-framework-version

I am trying to convert from .netCore5.0 to .netFramework4.0.
Here is my csproj:

```
<PropertyGroup>
        <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
        <TargetFramework>net4.0.0</TargetFramework>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager" Version="4.4.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging" Version="5.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Google.Protobuf" Version="3.11.4" />
        <PackageReference Include="Google.Protobuf.Tools" Version="3.11.4" />
        <PackageReference Include="Grpc.AspNetCore" Version="2.24.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Grpc.Tools" Version="2.27.0">
            <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
            <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
        </PackageReference>
        <PackageReference Include="System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter" Version="5.0.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="NLog" Version="4.7.10" />
        <PackageReference Include="NLog.Web.AspNetCore" Version="4.11.0" />
        <Content Include="appsettings.json">
            <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
        </Content>
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <Protobuf Include="Protos\monitor.proto" GrpcServices="Client" />
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

But almost all of the packages doesn`t work on .netFramework4.0.0, what should I do?

Also, it has to be the version 4.0.0, I do not have any other options about that.

Comment: do you really mean .NET 4.0 ? that is ... not going to work, and has been dead since 2016; any chance you mean .net 4.6.2 or something? that would be `net462`, i.e. `<TargetFramework>net462</TargetFramework>`; if you genuinely do mean .NET 4.0, then this applies, but with extra weight: https://blog.marcgravell.com/2020/01/net-core-net-5-exodus-of-net-framework.html

Comment: ***Why?!?!?!?!*** This is **not** going to be an easy "just replace .net5 with .netFramework4.0.00" kind of operation......

Comment: also: all your Grpc.AspNetCore code would still need to be re-written to use the google native transport instead - i.e. the server host needs to change; absolutely doable, but: more than fits in a comment; ultimately, what you're asking is "I have code written to use a 2021 API set, and I want to make it run on a framework that was released in 2010" - it is not going to be a "just change this number and click build" thing

Comment: The value "net4.0.0" is invalid for TargetFramework. Anyway, .NET 4.0 was released in 2010, and I don't think you have any chance of making Grpc work in .NET Framework 4.0. I think Marc Gravell is correct.

Comment: @A.Chiesa indeed - even  the google transport [Grpc.Core](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Grpc.Core) only goes down as far as 4.5

Comment: If you really mean .NET 4.0, then as the others have said - it's not going to work; there aren't any packages on Nuget that will backtrack that far (to my knowledge), certainly not one of the ones you're wanting to use.

Comment: My boss wants this done. I really mean .netFramework, but thanks for the answers, I will try to modify this.